# import many ascii files in a directory, read as array, print number of rows, columns for each file

Tags: numpy, pandas, scipy, arcpy

As a basic check for hundreds of ascii files, I'd like to double-check that each has the correct number of rows and columns. The first 6 lines of each file aren't part of the 23x23 matrix matrix that each contains. I've tried the various possibilities for reading the matrix size that I turned into comment lines (below), but now I'm thinking that I need a new way to read the arrays other than arcpy's listTables. I would be open to using modules used in pandas as well. Any ideas? Thanks.

```
import arcpy, numpy
from arcpy import env

env.workspace = r"C:\VMshared\small_example_valley5\SDepth1"

for file in arcpy.ListTables():
    #numpy.loadtxt(file,dtype = float, "#", delimiter = ' ', "#", skiprows = '6')
    outfile = numpy.loadtxt(file, skiprows = '6')
    print numpy.shape(outfile)
    #print enumerate(file)  
    #print len(file) + len(file.T)
    #print len(file) + map(len,file)
```

Comment: I think you're on the right track with numpy.  After you load each file you can check the shape to see if its the right size

Comment: I would do that using print numpy.shape(file), however, each iteration would give this as the following output: ()    ---apparently blank matrices. Another note is that the delimiter is a single space rather than a comma like with a csv

Comment: Forgive me if I'm misunderstanding, but shouldn't you do numpy.shape(outfile) or outfile.shape instead?

Comment: I hadn't though of that. How would the indent section look exactly in newbie terms? What does the outfile variable need to be defined as prior to calling it in print numpy.shape(outfile)?

Comment: Set outfile just like you have it then compare the shape of it to your desired shape

Comment: Similar to how have edited the code block? I have a feeling I'm missing something ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think numpy could be used for this.

```
for file in arcpy.ListTables():
        outfile = numpy.loadtxt(file, delimiter=" ", skiprows = 6)
        if outfile.shape != (23,23):
            print file + " has an incorrect number of rows or columns"
```

Comment: Hmmm..... I was seeing this error even before I tried your code so maybe it's something else. Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 7, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 690, in loadtxt
    fh = iter(open(fname, 'U'))
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'snowdepthN0001.asc' Thanks though, I was wondering how to tell the code to flag a suspect file. The weird thing about that error message is that it shows the actual ascii file name correctly.

Comment: So those files are located in the same directory that you're running your script/code from?

Comment: Sorry if I'm answering your questions incorrectly, but no, the script is saved in my documents folder - C:\Users\afullhar\Documents\ArcGIS. Are you implying it needs to be in the same folder as the ascii files?

Comment: Yes, or you need to specify the full path to your ascii files when trying to load them using numpy.  It would appear that file is the filename (e.g. 'snowdepthN0001.asc').  does that make sense?

Comment: Ok, news to me, so what I did was to move the script to the folder that contains the ascii files and ran it from there. I thought the folder which contains the files _was_ the full path directory, i.e. r"C:\VMshared\small_example_valley5\SDepth1". Now if I run the script from that directory I get a different error: Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 7, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 751, in loadtxt
    for i in xrange(skiprows):
TypeError: an integer is required

Comment: Shoot, sorry.  It's complaining because we passed a string instead of an integer.  I had skiprows = '6' when it should be skiprows = 6.

Comment: Awesome thanks, I think that did the trick. One snag up though is the matrix is really a spatial distribution, and it's surrounded with a row or column of -9999. I'm seeing this:     items = [conv(val) for (conv, val) in zip(converters, vals)]
ValueError: invalid literal for float(): -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999

Comment: hmmm.  Well, two thoughts.  1) strip those -9999 out before loading them with bumpy.   2) Check out geoPandas.  You can load spatial file directly into pandas which might save you the trouble of converting to ascii.